# NodeMCU multiple libraries error

Tags: iot, nodemcu, arduino-esp8266

How do I fix these errors in NodeMCU, which reports that multiple libraries were found for servo.h?

```
Multiple libraries were found for "Servo.h"
 Used: C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\2.4.1\libraries\Servo
 Not used: C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\libraries\Servo
exit status 1
'myservo' does not name a type
```

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49704566/multiple-libraries-were-found-servo-h

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multiple libraries were found servo.h](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49704566/multiple-libraries-were-found-servo-h)

Answer (score 0):

The NodeMCU boards use theire own librarys to controll servos. You can't use the normal servo library with the NodeMCU.